# Different colours being displayed for different versions of IE

Tags: css, html

I am facing an issue with CSS styles in ROR application in IE 9 and below versions.
It is displaying  orange color (#ff5b09)when > IE 9 and also in firefox, but taking grey color (#666) for <= IE9.
I need to make the IE 9 and below versions also display the orange color (#ff5b09). Please suggest. I am new to ROR. appreciate any help on the same.

CSS is making use of filters.
Style related to it is as following:

```
.ui-sortable .lesson, .boxy-inner .block.lesson, .router .slider .lesson
{
    background-color: #666;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom,
        from(#ff5b09), to(#f93d1e));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ff5b09, #f93d1e);
    /* MSIE */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient(
        StartColorStr='#ff5b09', EndColorStr='#f93d1e', GradientType=0);
}
```

Comment: Just remove the #666 and put the #ff5b09 there.

Answer (score 0):

`background-color: #666;`

Do you need this color(#666)?

if you don't then replace it with `#ff5b09`.

If you need it, then try this: put above statement at the end of all styles, some IE browser versions ignore all filters and gradients once they hit the `background-color` style. So, having it at the top could be causing issues.